# PayPal Integration Error: Payee account is invalid

Tags: c#, .net-core, paypal-sandbox

I am using PayPal REST API 1.9.1 in my dotnet core project. I have created sandbox account and when I am trying to make any payment getting "Payee account is invalid." error.

Api endpoint is "/v1/payments/payment" and payment method is "credit_card".

Below is code snippet:

```
string accessToken = new PayPal.Api.OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
        var apiContext = new PayPal.Api.APIContext(accessToken);
        // A transaction defines the contract of a payment.
        var transaction = new PayPal.Api.Transaction()
        {
            amount = new PayPal.Api.Amount()
            {
                currency = "USD",
                total = totalAmount,
                details = new PayPal.Api.Details()
                {
                    shipping = shipping,
                    subtotal = subTotal,
                    tax = tax
                }
            },
            description = description,
            item_list = new PayPal.Api.ItemList()
            {
                items = new List<PayPal.Api.Item>()
                {
                    new PayPal.Api.Item()
                    {
                        name = itemName,
                        currency = "USD",
                        price = "1",
                        quantity = "5",
                        sku = "sku"
                    }
                },
                shipping_address = new PayPal.Api.ShippingAddress
                {
                    city = "Johnstown",
                    country_code = "US",
                    line1 = "52 N Main ST",
                    postal_code = "43210",
                    state = "OH",
                    recipient_name = "Basher Buyer"
                }
            },
            invoice_number = invoice_number
        };
        // A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment.
        var payer = new PayPal.Api.Payer()
        {
            payment_method = "credit_card",
            funding_instruments = new List<PayPal.Api.FundingInstrument>()
            {
                new PayPal.Api.FundingInstrument()
                {
                    credit_card = new PayPal.Api.CreditCard()
                    {
                        billing_address = new PayPal.Api.Address()
                        {
                            city = "Johnstown",
                            country_code = "US",
                            line1 = "52 N Main ST",
                            postal_code = "43210",
                            state = "OH"
                        },
                        cvv2 = card.CVV,
                        expire_month = Convert.ToInt32(card.ExpirationMonth),
                        expire_year = Convert.ToInt32(card.ExpirationYear),
                        first_name = firstName,
                        last_name =lastName,
                        number = card.CardNumber,
                        type = card.CardType
                    }
                }
            },
            payer_info = new PayPal.Api.PayerInfo
            {
                email = "test@gmail.com"
            },
        };
        // A Payment resource; create one using the above types and intent as `sale`, 'order', 'none' or `authorize`
        var payment = new PayPal.Api.Payment()
        {
            intent = "sale",
            payer = payer,
            transactions = new List<PayPal.Api.Transaction>() { transaction }
        };
        // Create a payment using a valid APIContext
        var createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
```

Same code is working fine with payment method "paypal" by making minor changes in request.

How can I make it work for card payments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Api endpoint is "/v1/payments/payment" and payment method is "credit_card".

You are using an API and feature that was deprecated a long time (eight years?) ago.

Current integrations use the v2/checkout/orders API. As of this writing there is no SDK for them, use direct HTTPS calls to first obtain an access_token , then send payloads in JSON format.

- Standard integration: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate
- Advanced credit & debit cards add on: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced

Comment: Yes, it was version issue.  With v2 Api it works using direct https calls. Thanks a lot.